# Multiple Regex matches in C#

Tags: c#, python, regex

I'm used to web-scraping in Python but now I'm trying to do the same in C#, which seems to be a bit different.
The simple thing I want to do is done in python by this regex:

```
r'<a href="(.*?)">.+name="(.*?)"'
```

It simply grabs the URL and a name related to that link and returns a 2 dimensional array.

How is this done in C#?

Comment: Create an instance of RegEx with the regular expression, then use the Match method to get matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"<a href=""(.*?)"">.+name=""(.*?)""");

MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("URL={0}, Name={1}", match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```